Error al usar las api de google maps
Tengo dos APIKEY de google, una es para la geolocalización y la otra para el resto de opciones del mapa de google. Necesito usar las dos en una pantalla pero no funcionan juntas. Al descargar los script de cada apikey resulta que tiene varias funciones con el mismo nombre, entonces me da un error y no funciona el mapa.
¿Hay alguna forma de usar las dos apikey juntas en una misma página?

PHP, JS, Android, Kotlin, GTA, NFS, en que quieres usar las APIs?? Pon esos tags para que la gente pueda ayudarte...
